# How i can filter through an Array and return the correct property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, filter

I have a render method in my React Component. I want to display a specific URL, depending on the value of a prop. So, I made an array of Objects that correspond to my prop value options, along with the URL that each one has.

```
const SecurityModeOptions: any[] = [
  { securityMode: 'mode1', url: 'https://docs.mode1' },
  { securityMode: 'mode2', url: 'https://docs.mode2' },
  { securityMode: 'mode3', url: 'https://docs.mode3' }
];

  renderBasicMode = () => {
    const { securityMode } = this.props;
    const getSecurityModeURL = SecurityModeOptions.filter(
       url => SecurityModeOptions.SecurityMode === securityMode
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <NoResource
          icon="user-o"
          title="Security Mode"
          moreUrl={getSecurityModeURL()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

So, I made this filter function, that I call inside the `moreUrl` prop. The problem is I do not have a way to test that this functionality works, for the next few days. So, I was thinking, if you could take a look an tell me if there is something wrong with it.

I sense I did something funky, but I do not get any errors, and I am not sure, I did it correctly. Would be a huge help.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**

If, the securityMode in the `SecurityModeOption` matches the `this.props.securityMode`, the saw the corresponding URL in the moreUrl prop.

Comment: Is `getSecurityModeURL` really a function ? enter different `securityMode` and check to see if you can render the currect url in `NoResource` component

Comment: Start by opening dev tools console ...should see errors there. That's your first clue what's wrong

Comment: If I could do that, I would. I am unable to check this functionality for the next few days, and I am still a junior dev, so not really sure, this is working. Hence the question.

Comment: Can easily open any sandbox site and test your filter outside of react even and see what it returns. What is shown will throw errors

Comment: You can still mock it. you have the array of modes, you know you will get `securityMode` as props try to render something simple just to check you get no errors and the right url that you need

Answer (score 2):

Theres a couple things wrong with this. `getSecurityModeURL` will resolve to an array, not a function. So the line `moreUrl={getSecurityModeURL()}` will end up causing an error if called in the child.

If you wish `getSecurityModeURL` to resolve to a single object you need to use `.find` instead of `.filter`. So would end up looking like:

```
const getSecurityModeURL = SecurityModeOptions.find(
   x => x.SecurityMode === securityMode
);
```

and then passing it to child

`moreUrl={getSecurityModeURL.url || ''}`

As far as testing goes, it looks like you have sample data, why can't you test with it? Everything else looks fine.

Comment: `filter()` not used properly either

Comment: I can not test it, because the prop is not there, and I can not mock it. Only the default value is present currently. The rest of the functionality is coming in the next few days, but I don't want to wait with something that is wrong until then. Hhhmm, so I made quite a few mistakes. Should have known filter will return an array.. Need to remember that..

Comment: So give the prop a value, and then test it? I don't see what the problem is.